# Webflux + security with spring native - NoClassDefFoundError: WebMvcConfigurer

Tags: spring-webflux, graalvm-native-image, spring-native

This is about spring native, I'm facing the same issue in every web flux project I'm working on. I'm not able to generate the native image. Could anyone help please?

I'm working on a Mac (Catalina 10.15.6 (19G73)) and using OpenJDK Runtime Environment GraalVM CE 21.0.0.2 (build 11.0.10+8-jvmci-21.0-b06)

The error I'm getting is:

**Fatal error:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer**

**Error: Image build request failed with exit status 1**

This are my dependencies:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.experimental</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-native</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
            <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>9.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <!-- Customize Spring Boot classifier, useful in order to avoid a clash between Spring Boot repackaging and native-image-maven-plugin -->
        <classifier/>
        <!-- Customize native-image arguments with this property -->
        <native.build.args></native.build.args>
        <!-- `tiny` builder allows small footprint and reduced surface attack, you can also use `base` (the default) or `full` builders to have more tooling available in the image for an improved developer experience -->
        <!-- TODO Bring back "paketobuildpacks/builder:tiny" before 0.10.0 release -->
        <builder>dmikusa/graalvm-tiny</builder>
        <spring-native.version>0.9.2</spring-native.version>

        <project.encondig>UTF-8</project.encondig>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>${project.encondig}</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>${project.encondig}</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>

        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
        <maven.compiler.plugin.version>2.3.2</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
        <maven.resources.plugin.version>2.6</maven.resources.plugin.version>
        <maven.dependency.plugin.version>2.8</maven.dependency.plugin.version>
        <maven.deploy.plugin.version>2.7</maven.deploy.plugin.version>
        <maven.release.plugin.version>2.5.3</maven.release.plugin.version>
        <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.22.2</maven-surefire-plugin.version>

        <jackson.version>2.12.0</jackson.version>
        <jackson-bom.version>${jackson.version}</jackson-bom.version>
        <jacoco.version>0.8.5</jacoco.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.4.20-RC</kotlin.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>${classifier}</classifier>
                        <image>
                            <builder>${builder}</builder>
                            <env>
                                <BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>true</BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>
                                <BP_NATIVE_IMAGE_BUILD_ARGUMENTS>${native.build.args}</BP_NATIVE_IMAGE_BUILD_ARGUMENTS>
                            </env>
                        </image>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.experimental</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-aot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring-native.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>test-generate</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>test-generate</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>generate</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>generate</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.graalvm.nativeimage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>native-image-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>21.1.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <imageName>${project.artifactId}</imageName>
                        <buildArgs>${native.build.args}</buildArgs>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>native-image</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.experimental</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-native</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-native.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <profiles>
        <!-- Enable building a native image using a local installation of native-image with GraalVM native-image-maven-plugin -->
        <profile>
            <id>native-image</id>
            <properties>
                <!-- Avoid a clash between Spring Boot repackaging and native-image-maven-plugin -->
                <classifier>exec</classifier>
            </properties>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.graalvm.nativeimage</groupId>
                        <artifactId>native-image-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not happy with it, but this is a workaround. Adding the following piece of code in the pom.xml file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

And add in the properties file the following property:

spring.main.web-application-type=REACTIVE